# How do you retrieve the azimuth of an Android device?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, azimuth

*Azimuth* is defined by [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) as:

> An angular measurement in a
>   spherical coordinate system. The vector from an observer (origin) to a
>   point of interest is projected perpendicularly onto a reference plane;
>   the angle between the projected vector and a reference vector on the
>   reference plane is called the azimuth.

How can I get this value on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float [] orientation = SensorManager.getOrientation();
float azimuth = orientation[0];
```

See also: [SensorManager.getOrientation(...);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29)